General registry failed to cloned in Julia
I was updating the General registry in Julia. It is giving error as invalid value for enum code: -29056 as shown in the image (Error message).
This answer addresses similar issue but for me it's not resolving. General Registry failed to update in Julia
So I tried removing the general registry and the tried to clone it again but the error is still same for cloning also.
Because of this error I am not able to add any package using Pkg as it gives this error while updating General registry.
I am using julia version 1.10.3 and Ubuntu WSL as terminal.
